# What is <close> and gs: in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering, thread-local-storage

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oursz.png), I can see the following disassembly code:

```
...
mov eax, gs:0x14
...
call 0x8058210 <close>
...
```

What is `<close>` doing here?

And what is `gs:`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please include the code in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

> What does `<close>` mean here?

It is simply the information that address `0x8058210` (the address of the function called by the `call` instruction) is the address of the function `close`:

This means that the instruction `call 0x8058210` calls the function `close()`.

> And what is `gs:`?

On 16- and 32-bit x86 CPUs, so-called "selectors" are used whenever memory is accessed.

In very simple words, these "selectors" specify which memory area shall be accessed. The registers `cs`, `ds`, `es`, `fs`, `gs` and `ss` hold "selector" values and therefore specify memory areas.

By default, the instruction `mov eax, [0x14]` would access the address `0x14` in the memory area specified by the `ds` register. The `gs:` means that not the memory area specified by the `ds` register, but the memory area specified by `gs` register shall be accessed.

(By the way: I would have expected that the instruction is displayed as `mov eax, [gs:0x14]` or as `mov eax, gs:[0x14]`.)

Unlike 16-bit x86 operating systems, most (but not all) 32-bit operating systems store all code and data in the same memory area.

For this reason, you typically won't see instructions like `mov ax, ss:[ebp-0x10]` in code for such operating systems.

However, many operating systems use one or two additional memory areas (specified by the registers `fs` and/or `gs`).

Under Linux, the memory area specified by `gs` holds the so-called thread local storage.

Comment: From the screenshot, `gs:0x14` is where it's loading a stack cookie from, for `-fstack-protector-strong`.